# Time Machine Backup Failing with Error 11

Tags: macos, time-machine, backup, disk-utility, external-disk

I've been trying to run a Time Machine backup for the last couple of days (OSX 10.7.5 and Porsche LaCie 2TB); however, it has been constantly failing. Console is producing the following crash messages

```
16-01-01 3:56:47.345 PM ReportCrash: DebugSymbols was unable to start a spotlight query: spotlight is not responding or disabled.
16-01-01 3:56:49.601 PM com.apple.backupd: Indexing a file failed. Returned 1 for: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/zh_CN.lproj/NSProAboutPanel.nib, /Volumes/LaCie/Backups.backupdb/Main’s MacBook Pro/2016-01-01-125749.inProgress/DD6E0FAD-0DB6-45EA-B196-73EAB917DF42/Macintosh HD/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/zh_CN.lproj/NSProAboutPanel.nib
16-01-01 3:56:49.601 PM com.apple.backupd: Aborting backup because indexing of file failed.
16-01-01 3:56:49.601 PM com.apple.backupd: Stopping backup.
16-01-01 3:56:51.870 PM ReportCrash: Saved crash report for mds[844] version ??? (???) to /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/mds_2016-01-01-155651_localhost.crash
16-01-01 3:56:54.817 PM com.apple.launchd: (com.apple.metadata.mds[844]) Job appears to have crashed: Segmentation fault: 11
16-01-01 3:56:55.094 PM mds: (Normal) FMW: FMW 0 0
16-01-01 3:56:55.309 PM com.apple.backupd: Copied 926318 files (32.1 GB) from volume Macintosh HD.
16-01-01 3:56:55.309 PM com.apple.backupd: Copy stage failed with error:11
16-01-01 3:56:55.509 PM mds: (Error) Volume: Could not find requested backup type:2 for volume
16-01-01 3:57:07.134 PM com.apple.backupd: Backup failed with error: 11
```

I went to Disk Utility to verify/repair my disk, and I encountered the same problems as in [this problem with volume bitmap](https://calvinseah.wordpress.com/2014/03/05/volume-bitmap-needs-minor-repair-for-orphaned-blocks-an-easy-solution/) I followed the solution there about restarting in Recovery Mode and repairing with Disk Utility. This solved the issue with the volume bitmap. After this, I started another backup attempt, anticipating success. What was different about this was that the previous failures would tell me that it was backing up 40 GB, but then it would 40 GB and continue getting larger, unto about 130 GB, and then crash. This backup started by saying that it was backing up the entirety of my drive (roughly 400 GB). Much to my dismay, it got to about 40 GB, and then crashed with the error messages that I referenced. What can I do to correct these errors, and successfully backup my system?

Comment: Why are you still on 10.7.5? Is there a reason you haven't updated?

Comment: @IronCraftMan It's mostly a result of it keeps slipping my mind. One of these days, I'll get around to upgrading to El Capitan. I also finally got all of my programming things to play nicely, and there's a small part of me that fears an upgrade will break things.

Answer (score 1):

It took a while, but I found that I had some corrupted file that kept crashing the backup. Once that file was gone, the backup went smoothly.